# Build fails whenever I try to generate apk in react native using JDK -16

Tags: java, reactjs, apk

Many solutions I come across to use version between ( 15 < and > 8).

Previous version I used was working fine(It was not 16) and when I used 16, I come across this issue.

Any one tried with 16 or come across same issue and found any solution?

Error I got while running command react-native run-android in MAC

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible

Comment: try to use open-jdk-7 or 8 .... it will work

Comment: Please share more details. For examples the error message.